# Edit actions in a table view similar to ios notifications center

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsnotificationcenter, uitableviewrowaction

I need to develop a tableview with edit actions on rows that look similar to the ones on iOS Notification center.
The resources I have used so far, say that I can only edit the background color and width of edit actions. What I want is the custom look like that of the notifications in iOS Notifications Center.

See the annotated portion. This is what I want.

[image: See the annotated portion]

This is what I have managed so far :|

[image: This is what I have managed so far :|]

Any help / guidance would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried using image as: `action.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "rowActionPic")!)`

Comment: @DashAndRest I did....Ummm..you see how my row background is slightly smaller than the actual row height? So what happened was, when i use the patternImage (and I also set roundedCorners to acheive the iOS notifications center look), i ended up with repetitive images one below the other...  Also, I could not figure out how to change the color of text in each action :|

Comment: There are custom libraries for adding swipe actions - you could look at their code, and change necessary parts.

Comment: Can you point me to some?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating my own views as a part of the table view cell and adding custom animation..

**Sample Code:**
In my tableViewController:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    ....

    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer.init(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap))
    tableView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)

    let leftSwipeGesture = UISwipeGestureRecognizer.init(target: self, action: #selector(handleLeftSwipe(_:)))
    leftSwipeGesture.direction = .left
    tableView.addGestureRecognizer(leftSwipeGesture)

    let rightSwipeGesture = UISwipeGestureRecognizer.init(target: self, action: #selector(handleRightSwipe(_:)))
    rightSwipeGesture.direction = .right
    tableView.addGestureRecognizer(rightSwipeGesture)
}

func handleTap(_ gestureRecognizer: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
    let point = gestureRecognizer.location(in: self.tableView)
    if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForRow(at: point) {
        var shouldSelectRow = false
        if indexPathBeingEdited != nil {
            if indexPath == indexPathBeingEdited {
                shouldSelectRow = true
            } else {
                //handle close of the cell being edited already
                if let previousEditedCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPathBeingEdited!) as? NotificationCenterTableViewCell {
                    previousEditedCell.closeEditActions()
                    indexPathBeingEdited = nil
                }
            }
        } else {
            shouldSelectRow = true
        }
        if shouldSelectRow {
            tableView.selectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: .middle)
            tableView(tableView, didSelectRowAt: indexPath)
        }
    }
}

func handleLeftSwipe(_ gestureRecognizer: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
    let point = gestureRecognizer.location(in: self.tableView)
    if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForRow(at: point) {
        if indexPathBeingEdited != nil {
            if indexPath == indexPathBeingEdited {
                //Do nothing
            } else {
                //handle close of the cell being edited already
                if let previousEditedCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPathBeingEdited!) as? NotificationCenterTableViewCell {
                    previousEditedCell.closeEditActions()
                    indexPathBeingEdited = nil
                }
            }
        }
        //proceed with left swipe action
        if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? NotificationCenterTableViewCell {
            cell.handleLeftSwipe(gestureRecognizer)
            let notification = notificationsArray[indexPath.section].notificationItems[indexPath.row]

            //Update the title of Read button
            if notification.isNotificationRead {
                cell.readUnreadButtonLabel.text = "Unread"
            } else {
                cell.readUnreadButtonLabel.text = "Read"
            }
            indexPathBeingEdited = indexPath
        }
    }
}

func handleRightSwipe(_ gestureRecognizer: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
    let point = gestureRecognizer.location(in: self.tableView)
    if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForRow(at: point) {
        if indexPathBeingEdited != nil {
            if indexPath == indexPathBeingEdited {
                if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? NotificationCenterTableViewCell {
                    cell.closeEditActions()
                    indexPathBeingEdited = nil
                    //Update the title of Read button
                    cell.readUnreadButtonLabel.text = "Read"
                }
            } else {
                //handle close of the cell being edited already
                if let previousEditedCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPathBeingEdited!) as? NotificationCenterTableViewCell {
                    previousEditedCell.closeEditActions()
                    indexPathBeingEdited = nil
                    //Update the title of Read button
                    previousEditedCell.readUnreadButtonLabel.text = "Read"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In my table view cell:

```
    func handleLeftSwipe(_ gestureRecognizer: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
    if !isBeingEdited {
        //Action to open the edit buttons
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
            self.notificationHolderViewLeadingConstraint.constant -= 248
            self.notificationHolderViewTrailingConstraint.constant -= 248

            self.editActionsView.isHidden = false
            self.layoutIfNeeded()
        }, completion: { (success) in

        })
        isBeingEdited = true
    }
}

func closeEditActions() {
    if isBeingEdited {
        //Action to open the edit buttons
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
            self.notificationHolderViewLeadingConstraint.constant += 248
            self.notificationHolderViewTrailingConstraint.constant += 248

            self.editActionsView.isHidden = true
            self.layoutIfNeeded()
        }, completion: { (success) in

        })
        isBeingEdited = false
    }
}   


 override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    if let viewToRound = editActionsView {
        let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect:viewToRound.bounds,
                                byRoundingCorners:[.topRight, .topLeft, .bottomRight, .bottomLeft],
                                cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 20, height:  20))

        let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()

        maskLayer.path = path.cgPath
        viewToRound.layer.mask = maskLayer
    }
}
```

Just FYI, I have my edit buttons i.e., Read / View / Clear added to the editActionsView. The corresponding actions are hooked up with IBActions in my tableViewCell class.

The outcome is this:

[image: Final look]

Comment: Hello! Do you have an example repo with this notification like table view cell?

Comment: ummm..sorry i dont...I did it in my code directly. Hope you found a solution. If not, please let me know. I will be happy to help if i can.